# Authentication Ldap With spring security 4

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap

First, I apologize for my bad english.

I have a problem with the authentication with ldap for my application.

The object retrieve by the method ***SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()*** is always an **AnonymousUser** instead of **LdapUserDetailsImpl**

I have no idea what's the problem is ...

I tested with spring 3 (in simple application) and it works fine but I have to make it work with spring 4.

I would be very happy if someone could help me :)

**Here are my files :**

spring-security.xml (included in my application-context.xml)

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http disable-url-rewriting="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/accueil" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>   
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <csrf/>
</http> 

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"></authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

 <beans:bean id="ldapContextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://myldap/dc=test,dc=fr"/>
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=fr" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="secret"/>
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="ldapContextSource" />
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="ldapContextSource" />
                    <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:constructor-arg> 
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator"> 
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapContextSource"/>
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="ou=Utilisateurs"/>
                    <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/> 
                    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/> 
                </beans:bean> 
            </beans:constructor-arg> 
</beans:bean>
```

login.jsp

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login"></c:url>
        <form name="loginForm" action="${loginUrl}" class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nom d'utilisateur" required autofocus>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;

} @RequestMapping("/formateurs")
public ModelAndView loadFormateurs(ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal) {

    List<String> formations = formateurService.getFormationsList();

    List<CompetenceFormationData> competencesLst = competenceFormationService.getRowList();
    Map< Integer, String > competences = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      for(CompetenceFormationData comp : competencesLst) competences.put(comp.getIdCompetenceFormation(), comp.getLibelle());

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("formateurs");
    model.addObject("formations", formations); 
    model.addObject("formation","");
    model.addObject("competences", competences);
    model.addObject("competence", new CompetenceFormationData());  

    modelMap.addAttribute("user", SpringSessionScopedBeanDeprefixer.getUserPrincipal());

    return model;
}
```

SpringSessionsScopedBeanDeprefixer.java

```
 public static String getUserPrincipal(){
    String userName = null;
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        userName = principal.toString();
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Does the login page work?

Comment: The login page works with spring 3 but doesn't work with spring 4. I have the same login page for my project in spring 3 and spring 4.. It looks like the username isn't recognized (with spring 4) because I retrieve an object AnonymousUser